# Commutator of Hamiltonian and the spin sum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-spin, spin-models, spin-chains

For a 1-D Heisenberg quantum spin chain the Hamiltonian is given by:

$$H=-\sum_{j=0}^{N-1} J_{i,i+1}\boldsymbol{\sigma}_j^i \cdot\boldsymbol{\sigma}_{j+1}^i -\sum_{j=0}^{N}h_j\sigma_j^z$$

where $\boldsymbol{\sigma}^i$ is the Pauli matrix vector at site $j$, and the J's are coupling constants. I have seen that it commutes with $\sum_{j=0}^N\sigma_j^z$ :

$$[H,\sum_{j=0}^N\sigma_j^z]=0$$

However I have never seen it proven explicitly. My trouble derives from the fact that the Pauli matrices are of different particles and hence one must take the commutator of the tensor product which is of different size as the sum. Can someone explain how this may be done?

https://edu.itp.phys.ethz.ch/fs13/int/SpinChains.pdf

Comment: What are your attempts so far? Could you elaborate on what do you mean by '[...] which is of different size as the sum'?

Comment: Since we are taking the tensor product, we end up with a 4*4 matrix, compared to the 2*2 matrix of $\sigma^z$. I tried using ladder operators, however I have not managed.

Comment: I see. Note however that $\sigma_i^z$ is a tensor product of operators too. See for example [the notation introduced in the corresponding Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_model_(quantum)). Does that help? Of course, this holds for $\sigma_i^x$ and $\sigma_i^y$ too. So the operators in the Hamiltonian (and the Hamiltonian itself) are operators on the tensor product space.

Comment: The sigma's on different sites commute with each other as they act on different spaces

Comment: Why do they commute exactly? I have never seen such a result. Is there a proof?

Comment: @abc See for example [equation 1.10 in these notes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-05-quantum-physics-ii-fall-2013/lecture-notes/MIT8_05F13_Chap_08.pdf). Further, also in the notes you've linked this is stated in equation $2$ - the sigmas of different sites commute due to the Kronecker delta on the right-hand side.